# Pass a test result to ITestResult in Selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I need to pass a result value to the `check` method that I have.

```
@Test
    public void test1()
    {
        test = extent.createTest("Test Case 4 : Checking displayed date against current date",
                "Checking if the date displayed on the check in and check out box is equal to the current date");

        String checkin = driver.findElement(By.id("from")).getAttribute("value");
        test.info(checkin);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());

        if (checkin.equals(timeStamp))
        {
            test.info("The checkin in date " + checkin + " is equal to the current date " + timeStamp);
        } else
        {
            test.info("The checkin in date " + checkin + " does not equal the current date " + timeStamp);
        }

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void check(ITestResult result) throws IOException
    {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            String screenshotPath = GetScreenshot.capture(driver);
            test.fail("Test Case Failed");
            test.info(result.getThrowable());
            test.info("Screenshot Below : " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath));

        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
        {
            test.skip("Test Case Has Been Skipped");
        } else
        {
            test.pass("Test Case Passed");
        }
    }
```

So what I want to accomplish is if the `checkin` is equal to the `timeStamp` then the test should pass and if `checkin` is not equal to the `timeStamp` the test should fail. For my current code, the tests pass in both the situations.

Is there anyway that I could pass a `test.fail()` or something to the `check` method.

I tried `check(ITestResult.FAILURE);` which didn't work.

I also tried `check((ITestResult) test.fail("Test has Failed"));` which threw a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your actual text case "@test" have an assertion for the expected result. If the assertion is passed, the test case will have a status passed in after method and vice versa.

```
//Assertion Example in Testng
Assert.assertEquals(checkin, timestamp);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.